# Link from webpage to make shortcut on phone

Tags: android, ios, html

So I know you can set webpages the bookmark on a phones homepage, almost like an app. Is there a way to set a link from a webpage so a person simply clicks a link (one for android, one for apple) and it automatically tells the phone what to do (rather than go through all the phone settings etc)?

Comment: Not in iPhone/ios - the user must select the share option in Safari and select "add to home screen"

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. Never mind